# r data simulations using parLapply

Tags: r

I am trying to simulate using the following code and data.For each of the iterations it is simulating `n` from `rpois` and then `n` values from function `rbeta`.This bit is working fine.

The only issue is that for each of `n` it should get`id` from the table below based on probability weighted(`id_prob`) sampling using function `sample` but for some reason it is only getting one `ID` for all values of `n`.

```
cl <- makeCluster(num_cores)
clusterEvalQ(cl,library(evir))
clusterExport(cl, varlist=c("Sims","ID","id_prob","beta_a","beta_b")
Sims<-10000

set.seed(0)
system.time(x1<-parLapply(cl,1:Sims, function(i){
                                            id<-sample(ID,1,replace=TRUE,prob=id_prob)
                                              n<-rpois(1,9)
                                              rbeta(n,beta_a[id],beta_b[id])
                                             }

))

 ID Rate id_prob Beta_a Beta_b
  1 1.5  16.7%    0.5   0.5
  2 2    22.2%    0.4   0.4
  3 1    11.1%    0.3   0.3
  4 1.5  16.7%    0.6   0.6
  5 2    22.2%    0.1   0.1
  6 1    11.1%    0.2   0.2
```

Comment: Is this the whole simulation? Because then you can rewrite the whole thing much more efficiently, without requiring clusters.

Comment: @Laterow how can you make it more efficient?I am trying to run 1 million sims and the table above in reality has 100000 rows.